# update xml node value by 1 with simplexml. Is it possible?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml, xmlnode

I have an XML file with the following layout. When a user views a wordpress post, the id get's written to an xml file along with a `<postviews>` node with a default value of 1 like so…

```
<posts>
    <post id="22640">
        <postviews>1</postviews>
    </post>
    <post id="7780">
        <postviews>1</postviews>
    </post>
</posts>
```

How can I write an update query so that when the wordpress post is seen again the postviews value for the specific post id is updated by a value of 1 so it would look like…

```
<posts>
    <post id="22640">
        <postviews>2</postviews>
    </post>
    <post id="7780">
        <postviews>1</postviews>
    </post>
</posts>
```

It seems like I'm having trouble targeting the right node. How can I update the child of a node with the specific post id?

Thanks, James

Comment: post edits as answer and close question (or I'll do it,if u want to).

Comment: Post your own answer rather than appending it to your question! :)

Comment: Will do. Thanks for the advice, I'm a bit of a newbie to this site so apologies :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to find the answer myself. Here is the code that both adds a new node if the post id isn't in the file and updates the node value by 1 if it is…

```
//Get the wordpress postID
$postID = get_the_ID();

$postData = get_post($postID);

// echo $postID.'<br />'.$postData->post_title.'<br />'.$postData->post_date_gmt.'<br />';

$xmlFile = '/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/giraffetest/test.xml';

// load the document
$xml = simplexml_load_file($xmlFile);

// Check to see if the post id is already in the xml file - has it already been set?
$nodeExists = $xml->xpath("//post[@id=".$postID."]");

//Count the results
$countNodeExists = count($nodeExists);

if($countNodeExists > 0) { // If the ID is already in the file

    // echo 'ID already here';

    // get the correct node
    $result = $xml->xpath("//post[@id=".$postID."]/postviews");

    // heres the trick - the first result of xpath, and the node value (stored in [0])
    $result[0][0] = $result[0][0]+1; 

} else { // If the ID isn;'t there, add a new entry in the xml file for the post

    //echo 'ID added';

    $postNode = $xml->addChild('post'); // adding a new <post> to the top level node
    $postNode->addAttribute('id', $postID); // adding a <postid> inside the new <post>
    $postNode->addChild('postviews', 1); // adding a postviews inside the new <post>
}

// save the updated document
$xml->asXML($xmlFile);
```